# Opencv 2.4 snakeImage C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I have looked at the opencv 2.4 reference and I cannot find an equivalent of snakeImage. Therefore what other methods can I implement to achieve the same result?

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you mean Active contour models - snakes???

Comment: Yeh that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use the definition of the `snake` of previous releases (eg. `opencv2.0`).
[snake opencv 2.0](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#snakeimage)
It works efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach: [Active Contour (Snake) with OpenCV](http://blog.danielesser.de/2008/08/06/showcase-active-contour-snake-with-opencv/)

But search on Google, you'll find more interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

It was moved to legacy.
Python binding: cv2.cv.SnakeImage()